# UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation [IPad]

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uidatepicker, shouldautorotate

**- Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIDatePickerContainerViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES**

> Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation
> 0  CoreFoundation                 0x9d94 __exceptionPreprocess
> 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183d0 objc_exception_throw
> 2  CoreFoundation                 0xf7300 __CFDictionaryCreateGeneric
> 3  UIKitCore                      0x243b54 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations]
> 4  UIKitCore                      0x24377c -[UIViewController __withSupportedInterfaceOrientation:apply:]
> 5  UIKitCore                      0x175560 -[UIViewController setInterfaceOrientation:]
> 6  UIKitCore                      0x172090 -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]
> 7  UIKitCore                      0x1d940 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
> 8  UIKitCore                      0xd0b68 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke
> 9  CoreAutoLayout                 0x4fcc -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
> 10 UIKitCore                      0x105c200 -[UIView _postMovedFromSuperview:]
> 11 UIKitCore                      0x1e8b8 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
> 12 UIKitCore                      0x3d9988 __67-[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2
> 13 UIKitCore                      0x30f58 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
> 14 UIKitCore                      0x3c0bac __67-[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]_block_invoke
> 15 UIKitCore                      0xcd458 +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
> 16 UIKitCore                      0xa054c +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
> 17 UIKitCore                      0x2b1cdc -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]
> 18 UIKitCore                      0x7fb8b4 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_3
> 19 UIKitCore                      0x2010d0 +[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:]
> 20 UIKitCore                      0x2b1864 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2
> 21 UIKitCore                      0x1f2580 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]
> 22 UIKitCore                      0x1f243c _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition
> 23 UIKitCore                      0x76430c __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_3
> 24 UIKitCore                      0x1a0430 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run]
> 25 UIKitCore                      0x1a0364 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush]
> 26 libdispatch.dylib              0x2320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
> 27 libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout
> 28 libdispatch.dylib              0x126a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
> 29 libdispatch.dylib              0x122f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
> 30 CoreFoundation                 0x98d18 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
> 31 CoreFoundation                 0x7a650 __CFRunLoopRun
> 32 CoreFoundation                 0x7f4dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> 33 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal
> 34 UIKitCore                      0x39d37c -[UIApplication _run]
> 35 UIKitCore                      0x39cfe0 UIApplicationMain
> 36 eldman                         0x1e234 main + 17 (AppDelegate.swift:17)
> 37 ???                            0x1da5c8dec (Missing)

I got this crash report from crashlytics, this is happening for Ipad Only. How can we fix the autoRotation in UIDatePicker?
I want the autorotation of UIViewControllers to work as it is in my application and can't change anything, Also i am not able to find the controller where it is crashing.
I am, also not able to find anything about UIDatePickerContainerViewController.

I know there are several similar questions on stackoverflow about autorotation but i am not able to find anything useful about UIDatePicker Causing crash in iPad due to rotation. This is about UserInterfaceIdioms in my application:
[image]

The code in AppDelegate:

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}

struct AppUtility {
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Whole application works in portrait mode only, In just one view controller which is supposed to work in landscape only, the code is :
 `AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight)`